# Got a crash after migrating androidx and android sdk 29?

Tags: android, listview, crash, androidx

After migrating to androidX, I got an exception

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
    at android.widget.ListView.clearRecycledState(ListView.java:545)
    at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:531)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1556)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2170)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
    at androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:625)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:730)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17666)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5577)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2383)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2105)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6396)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:876)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:688)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:623)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:862)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

I am using `SwipeRefreshLayout` in `PullAndLoadListView`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/appbackground"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.org.appname.view.PullAndLoadListView
        android:id="@+id/listFeed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp">
    </com.org.appname.view.PullAndLoadListView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    layout="@layout/buttons_bottom" /></RelativeLayout>
```

trying so many StackOverflow answers none of them helped me?

## Edit

I am able to trace the issue, actually in `SwipeRefreshLayout.java`method name onLayout has a crash on this line `child.layout(childLeft, childTop, childLeft + childWidth, childTop + childHeight);`.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    final int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    final int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (mTarget == null) {
        ensureTarget();
    }
    if (mTarget == null) {
        return;
    }
    final View child = mTarget;
    final int childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    final int childTop = getPaddingTop();
    final int childWidth = width - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    final int childHeight = height - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
    child.layout(childLeft, childTop, childLeft + childWidth, childTop + childHeight);
    int circleWidth = mCircleView.getMeasuredWidth();
    int circleHeight = mCircleView.getMeasuredHeight();
    mCircleView.layout((width / 2 - circleWidth / 2), mCurrentTargetOffsetTop,
            (width / 2 + circleWidth / 2), mCurrentTargetOffsetTop + circleHeight);
}
```

Comment: This could be the issue: `com.org.appname.view.PullAndLoadListView`. Have you activated `Jetifier`?

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv Yes, `gradle.properties` I have this two flags enables
'android.enableJetifier=true`
`android.useAndroidX=true'

Comment: Probably it's a problem of `PullAndLoadListView`. Add this to check

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman ok, I will be attached this file for your refrence.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman Please follow this link (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DR9M1TFm0xwEeudqqisox9XqD4jUaMx4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Check my answer and also check your codebase to find out the culprit. `PullToRefreshListView` check there or it's parent

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you're replacing existing layout params of type `AbsListView.LayoutParams` with `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, which causes the `Exception`. Try to set correct `LayoutParams`.

If you want to modify existing `LayoutParams` then follow the steps:

**First,** Get existing `LayoutParams` of view by calling `getLayoutParams()`

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams()
//modify layoutParams here
```

**Then,** To refresh the layout call `requestLayout()`

```
view.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Okay, but actually which class or method should i need to place this code?

Comment: in my activity 
`listFeed = (PullAndLoadListView) findViewById(R.id.listFeed);
  AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  listFeed.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
  listFeed.requestLayout();
  listFeed.setOnLoadMoreListener(this);`
but still got same crashed, not helped me.

Comment: I am not cast anything in both classes?

Comment: Then add your activity

Comment: Ok please follow this link for superclass (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DR9M1TFm0xwEeudqqisox9XqD4jUaMx4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. here is the correct one (https://drive.google.com/file/d/19rON9Mwqivogquu1dVaJLe0JF-muhxUT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Didn't find anything on that file, Can you search in your project to check? Also check in your adapter. Your logcat didn't point anything related to your local files